# How to embed inset plots generated with seaborn lmplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

In seaborn `sns.lmplot` returns [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) object. I would like to plot an inset. Here is a self contained "working" example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
df_string='time\tsex\tage\tval1\tval2\n1\tM\t18\t0.285837375\t4.402793733\n2\tM\t18\t0.234239365\t2.987464305\n3\tM\t18\t0.820418465\t3.23991295\n4\tM\t18\t0.826027695\t9.707366329\n5\tM\t18\t0.625449525\t2.971235344\n6\tM\t18\t0.485980081\t5.517575471\n7\tM\t18\t0.136163546\t3.620177216\n8\tM\t18\t0.784944053\t5.116294718\n9\tM\t18\t0.981526403\t6.348155198\n10\tM\t18\t0.822237037\t4.682176522\n1\tF\t22\t0.104339381\t5.434133736\n2\tF\t22\t0.788797127\t0.843869877\n3\tF\t22\t0.997986894\t8.765048753\n4\tF\t22\t0.51167857\t2.054679646\n5\tF\t22\t0.328416139\t6.581617426\n6\tF\t22\t0.317804112\t1.584234393\n7\tF\t22\t0.489944956\t8.564257177\n8\tF\t22\t0.207348127\t1.346020575\n9\tF\t22\t0.727347344\t7.487993859\n10\tF\t22\t0.252917798\t8.822904862\n11\tF\t22\t0.690106636\t6.728470474\n12\tF\t22\t0.508078197\t2.489437246\n'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_string), sep='\t')


# running a moving average
df_tmp = df.groupby(['sex', 'age']).rolling(min_periods=1, window=3, center=True).mean()

df_tmp.plot()
```

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator import inset_axes, mark_inset

df_to_plot = df_tmp.reset_index()
g = sns.lmplot(x='time',y='val1',hue="sex",x_estimator=np.mean,height=10, aspect=1,
                   data=df_to_plot, logx= True, legend_out=True, truncate=True)

g.axes[0][0].xaxis.set_label_text('t [sec]')
g.set(yscale="log")   

ax = g.axes[0][0]
axins = inset_axes(ax, "30%", "40%")
g_inset = sns.lmplot(x='time',y='val1',hue="sex",x_estimator=np.mean, data=df_to_plot, legend_out=False)
```

But I get the following two plots instead of embedding the second one in the inset plot:

[image]

[image]

In the end I would like to have code that knows where there is a clear white space and put the inset cleanly inside it, something like this [example](https://scipython.com/blog/inset-plots-in-matplotlib/) by [Christian](https://scipython.com/blog/author/christian/):

[image]

---

FWIW, my toy set data looks like this in a tabular format:

[image]

Comment: From the code it doesn't look like there is any reason to use `lmplot` here. If instead you use a `regplot`, you can draw that on any matplotlib axes.

Comment: I think searching automatically for a clear white space is the hardest part here, as there isn't a clear solution for that

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the bigger real dataFrame I have 10 different hue cues. What did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `FacetGrid` produces its own figure, `lmplot` cannot be used inside an axes.
You will need to plot as many `regplot`s as you need instead.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df_string="""time\tsex\tage\tval1\tval2\n1\tM\t18\t0.285837375\t4.402793733\n
2\tM\t18\t0.234239365\t2.987464305\n
3\tM\t18\t0.820418465\t3.23991295\n
4\tM\t18\t0.826027695\t9.707366329\n
5\tM\t18\t0.625449525\t2.971235344\n
6\tM\t18\t0.485980081\t5.517575471\n
7\tM\t18\t0.136163546\t3.620177216\n
8\tM\t18\t0.784944053\t5.116294718\n
9\tM\t18\t0.981526403\t6.348155198\n
10\tM\t18\t0.822237037\t4.682176522\n
1\tF\t22\t0.104339381\t5.434133736\n
2\tF\t22\t0.788797127\t0.843869877\n
3\tF\t22\t0.997986894\t8.765048753\n
4\tF\t22\t0.51167857\t2.054679646\n
5\tF\t22\t0.328416139\t6.581617426\n
6\tF\t22\t0.317804112\t1.584234393\n
7\tF\t22\t0.489944956\t8.564257177\n
8\tF\t22\t0.207348127\t1.346020575\n
9\tF\t22\t0.727347344\t7.487993859\n
10\tF\t22\t0.252917798\t8.822904862\n
11\tF\t22\t0.690106636\t6.728470474\n
12\tF\t22\t0.508078197\t2.489437246\n"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_string), sep='\t')


import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for (n, grp) in df.groupby("sex"):
    sns.regplot(x='time',y='val1', x_estimator=np.mean,
                   data=grp, logx= True, truncate=True)

ax.xaxis.set_label_text('t [sec]')
ax.set(yscale="log")   

axins = inset_axes(ax,  "30%", "40%" ,loc="lower right", borderpad=3)

for (n, grp) in df.groupby("sex"):
    sns.regplot(x='time',y='val1', x_estimator=np.mean,
                   data=grp, truncate=True, ax=axins)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Since matplotlib 3, you can use ax.inset_axes and not go through the mpl_toolkit
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version with `matplotlib` 3, using [Axes.inset_axes] instead of `mpl_toolkits` (I tried that example and it didn't work for me):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df_string="""time\tsex\tage\tval1\tval2\n1\tM\t18\t0.285837375\t4.402793733\n
2\tM\t18\t0.234239365\t2.987464305\n
3\tM\t18\t0.820418465\t3.23991295\n
4\tM\t18\t0.826027695\t9.707366329\n
5\tM\t18\t0.625449525\t2.971235344\n
6\tM\t18\t0.485980081\t5.517575471\n
7\tM\t18\t0.136163546\t3.620177216\n
8\tM\t18\t0.784944053\t5.116294718\n
9\tM\t18\t0.981526403\t6.348155198\n
10\tM\t18\t0.822237037\t4.682176522\n
1\tF\t22\t0.104339381\t5.434133736\n
2\tF\t22\t0.788797127\t0.843869877\n
3\tF\t22\t0.997986894\t8.765048753\n
4\tF\t22\t0.51167857\t2.054679646\n
5\tF\t22\t0.328416139\t6.581617426\n
6\tF\t22\t0.317804112\t1.584234393\n
7\tF\t22\t0.489944956\t8.564257177\n
8\tF\t22\t0.207348127\t1.346020575\n
9\tF\t22\t0.727347344\t7.487993859\n
10\tF\t22\t0.252917798\t8.822904862\n
11\tF\t22\t0.690106636\t6.728470474\n
12\tF\t22\t0.508078197\t2.489437246\n"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_string), sep='\t')


import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

for (n, grp) in df.groupby("sex"):
    sns.regplot(x='time',y='val1', x_estimator=np.mean,
                   data=grp, logx= True, truncate=True)

plt.gcf().gca().xaxis.set_label_text('t [sec]')
plt.gcf().gca().set(yscale="log")   

axins = plt.gcf().gca().inset_axes([0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])

for (n, grp) in df.groupby("sex"):
    sns.regplot(x='time',y='val1', x_estimator=np.mean,
                   data=grp, truncate=True, ax=axins)

plt.show()
```

[image]